# How can i use OnLongClick Listener on more than 1 buttons in a onLongClick Method in same class

Tags: android, event-handling, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener, android-event

Here is my Code ...

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        text.setText("Application Created");
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Mybutton);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn1.setOnLongClickListener(**this**);*(Error Generated here)*
    }

public boolean onLongClick( View v)
{


    return  true;
}
```

i am trying to use on long click listener on more than two buttons and handle them in a single method (public boolean onLongClick(View v)) by using switch case. I tried my code but their is an error generated when i pass    **btn1.setOnLongClickListener(this);**  "this" in the braces" i am handling this event in the same class.

Comment: use switch case in longClick , switch(view.getId()) and identify your buttons with their respective ID's

Comment: Thank you so much Sir! For trying to help me but i am facing error in

Comment: btn1.setOnLongClickListener(**this**);*(Error Generated here)* this section can you please help me in this part

Comment: make your class implement onLongClickListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Implement your activity with the interface View.OnLongClickListener
**2)** Override Boolean method will generate as onLongClick, where you can write your switch case for the buttons.
**3)** initialize the button with setOnLongClickListener(this) as `button.setOnLongClickListener(this);`[onCreate]

**Sample as below-**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnLongClickListener{

    private Button btnOne, btnTwo, btnThree;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idBtnOne);
        btnTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idBtnTwo);
        btnThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idBtnThree);

        btnOne.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        btnTwo.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        btnThree.setOnLongClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.idBtnOne:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Long pressed on Button 1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.idBtnTwo:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Long pressed on Button 2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.idBtnThree:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Long pressed on Button 3",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

btn1.setOnLongClickListener(this);

and impliment your class with `View.OnLongClickListener`

and then override this method

```
  @Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()){
     case R.id. :
     break;
  }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use **this** as OnLongClickListener your class should implements the interface View.OnLongClickListener and it's method, for example:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnLongClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        btn1.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

I believe you already did same for btn2.setOnClickListener(this) and OnClickListener interface.